# XBee not communicating with Arduino connected

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, xbee, zigbee

I have two XBee S2 modules. Both are communicating when I connect them directly to my computer and check via X-CTU terminal. The problem is when I try to send data wirelessly by connecting both of them with two Arduinos there is no communication at all. It doesn't send any value.

This is the code for the receiving side:

```html
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial XBSerial = SoftwareSerial(2, 3);

int BackMotorForward =  6;
int BackMotorReverse =  5;
int FrontMotorRight  = 10;
int FrontMotorLeft   =  9;
int sv1 = 0;
int sv2 = 0;

void setup ()
{
    pinMode(BackMotorForward, OUTPUT); // Initialize the pin as an output.
    pinMode(BackMotorReverse, OUTPUT); // Initialize the pin as an output.
    pinMode(FrontMotorRight,  OUTPUT); // Initialize the pin as an output.
    pinMode(FrontMotorLeft,   OUTPUT); // Initialize the pin as an output.

    Serial.begin(9600);

    // Set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
    XBSerial.begin(9600);
    // XBSerial.println(".");
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.write(XBSerial.read());
    if (XBSerial.available())
    {
        sv1 = XBSerial.read();
        Serial.write(sv1);
    }
    if (XBSerial.available())
    {
        sv2 = XBSerial.read();
        Serial.write(sv2);
    }
    if (sv1 < 280)
    {
        Serial.write("backward");
        digitalWrite(BackMotorForward, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(BackMotorReverse,LOW);
    }
    else if (sv1 > 380)
    {
        Serial.write("forward");
        digitalWrite(BackMotorReverse,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(BackMotorForward,LOW);
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(BackMotorForward,LOW);
        digitalWrite(BackMotorReverse,LOW);
    }
    if (sv2 > 380)
    {
        Serial.write("left");
        digitalWrite(FrontMotorRight, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(FrontMotorLeft,LOW);
    }
    else if (sv2 < 280)
    {
        Serial.write("right");
        digitalWrite(FrontMotorLeft,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(FrontMotorRight,LOW);
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(FrontMotorRight,LOW);
        digitalWrite(FrontMotorLeft,LOW);
    }
}
```

This is the code for the sending side:

```html
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial XBSerial =  SoftwareSerial(2, 3);
const int xpin = A0;                  // x-axis of the accelerometer
const int ypin = A1;                  // y-axis

void setup()
{
    // Initialize the serial communications:
    pinMode(xpin, INPUT); //x axis
    pinMode(ypin, INPUT); //y axis

    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("testing");

    // Set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
    XBSerial.begin(9600);
    XBSerial.println("testing!!!");
}

void loop()
{
    // Print the sensor values:
    Serial.print(analogRead(xpin));
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(analogRead(ypin));

    // Print a tab between values:
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println();

    // Delay before next reading:
    delay(100);

    int val = analogRead(xpin);

    int val2 = analogRead(ypin);

    XBSerial.print(val); //Changed from write to print
    XBSerial.print(val2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was a really stupid mistake. I was using softwareserial pins 2,3 for XBee, but instead I was connecting their pins directly to pin 0,1 (rx,tx) of the Arduino. That's the reason there was no communication.